# Is it possible to rotate text using CSS 2.1?

Tags: css, flying-saucer, rotatetransform

I am using [FlyingSaucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) to generate an image from HTML and I am restricted to CSS 2.1.  I would like to use CSS to rotate text in a `<div>` but these rotate styles are only supported on CSS 3:

```
-o-transform: rotate(-15deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
transform: rotate(-15deg);
```

I cannot use Javascript, only HTML and CSS.

Is there any way to rotate text using CSS 2.1?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; what kind of project is it that limits you to use CSS 2.1 in December of 2014? I'm currently also building a site where there are still IE8 users, but hey – they wont see any modern things. (Like custom web fonts and slightly rotated text for headings). But I try to make sure that the site is usable for IE8 users, even if it does not look the same.

Comment: My project involves a server-side creation of an image using FlyingSaucer which is restricted to using CSS 2.1.  I am trying to determine if there is another way to rotate text and unfortunately I believe the answer is no :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible. Flying Saucer only works with CSS 2.1 and some extensions properties as per documentation: https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_43

Answer (score 2):

No. There are other technologies (SVG, Flash, …) but if you are restricted to CSS 2.1 (which is more than ten years old) I guess you also can't use any other technology of the current age.